# Copy a single row onEdit of Column A to "New" to another Google spreadsheet - NOT tab in the same sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to be able to select "New" from either a drop down menu or check box which will then copy that row only to another sheet in another file on google drive.  I can get the script to work within the "same" spreadsheet, but having trouble getting it to copy to another external spreadsheet.

```
function addSingleJobtoDriver1Sheet(e) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named driver 1
  // target sheet of move to named todays work
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 1 or A
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Driver 1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "New") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn()1;
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1-2Kuv9XGD-srJ_TwZpvCCxiW0qghyl12IelpdeNWlIc");
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Todays Work");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);

  } 
}
```

I already have existing onEdits, so I assume I do what I have already done with other onEdit scrips and add it like I have here eg: **addSingleJobtoDriver1(e)**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  activeCheckboxes(e)
  moveToField(e)
  addSingleJobtoDriver1(e)

}

function activeCheckboxes(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== 'NEW JOB FORM') return; 
  if (e.range.getColumn() !== 5) return;
  if (e.value == 'TRUE') {
    switch (e.range.getRow()) {
      case 28:
        RecordSingleJobEntry()
        break;
      case 29:
        sheet.showRows(31,5);
        break;
      case 33:
        AddRecurringJobToDatabase()
        break;
      case 4:
        lookupJobNo()
        break;
      case 6:
        ClearForm()
    }
  } else {
    switch (e.range.getRow()) {
      case 27:
        sheet.hideRows(30,5);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.  I'm pulling my hair out.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This function requires an installable onEdit trigger since it requires permission to write to another file.  Also note you cannot call this function directly from the script editor because it requires an event object to populate the parameter e.

[image]

Sorry I gave you the wrong code

Source Sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thank MetaMan. But it is not working?  I created the scipt as per your example, saved, added the existing onEdit I already have:
/Users/marianne/Desktop/Screen Shot 2021-05-14 at 2.12.28 pm.png

Comment: function onEdit(e) {
  activeCheckboxes(e)
  moveToField(e)
  addSingleJobtoDriver1(e)
}

Comment: function addSingleJobtoDriver1(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
 if(sh.getName() == "Driver 1" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "New") {
     var tss = spreadsheetApp.openById("1-2Kuv9XGD-srJ_TwZpvCCxiW0qghyl12IelpdeNWlIc");
    var tsh = tss.getSheetByName("Todays Work");
    var tgt = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(tgt);
  }
}

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to use an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) onEdit trigger. This means that you need to rename your funciton from `onEdit` to soemthing else and bind the trigger to it manually as per documentation.

Comment: Thank you.  You are a legend.  Works perfectly.